# How do I know what Encryption algorithm was used

Tags: cryptography, ascii

I am a newbee in cryptography and I am trying to decrypt some ciphertext with no knowledge of the keyword. However this ciphertext consists of ASCII characters.

Is there any way for me to easily covert ASCII characters to plain letters??
 Thank you!

Comment: "covert ASCII characters to plain letters' makes no sense. Do some studying what ASCII is.

Comment: Show us a sample of the cyphertext.  If it is a classical cypher, then try it as a Caesar (only 26 possible keys) or as a Vigenere.

Answer (score 0):

An encrypted string will consist of binary data. It won't be limited to printable ASCII characters. Rendering it out as a string should show it as garbage, possibly with lots of boxes where unprintable characters would appear.

If it's entirely alphanumeric and some punctuation, then it might not be encrypted so much as Base64 encoded.

What you're asking for - (what I think is) converting garbage to something printable - would destroy the actual binary string of encrypted data. If you can do it in an easily reversable way though, by using a Base64 encoding and decoding, you can at least make it printable without ruining it. Base64 encoding will make the string significantly longer though, as it doesn't use the character space as efficiently.